# Can i HTML's <style> tag have <style class="abc"> or <style id="abc">?

Tags: html

i'm will use this code.

```
<html>
<head>..</head>
<body>
<style class="sidebar-extention">
...
</style>
<style class="footer-extention">
...
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

style tag add class. is better comment?

```
<html>
<head>..</head>
<body>
<style>
/* sidebar-extention */
...
</style>
<style>
/* footer-extention */
...
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

style tags will extention = on -> activity code.

Answer (score 1):

You could... but why?

Comments are generally better. But why so many `<style>`? Why not put it under ONE tag with comments, or separate CSS files?

More about `<style>` tags:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style

More about CSS files:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: i'm not downvote. may i used comment. If the user enters the color, the corresponding CSS is added, so it will not be activated if the color is not entered.

Comment: It's okay, I didn't think it was you, just whoever downvoted would be nice if they said why :)

Answer (score 0):

Either will work, it all depends what you want to do with your code. There is, however a hierarchical structure with classes and ids where ids are more specific and each element can only have one id whereas elements can have more than one class. Common practice is to use classes more often and shy away from ids.

Take a look at this article which fully explains the differences.

https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/